# How do you get a specific time in the past in C#?

Tags: c#, timestamp

For example: Let's say I wanted a random time from the date 01/03/20 -> It can return 23:23:45 or 07:12:34 etc.. It that possible in C# ?

Comment: Do you want a _random_ time, or a _specific_ time?

Comment: `random` time for `specific` date :)

Comment: Just a random time for a specific date*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
public static DateTime GetRandomTime(DateTime date)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return date.Date.AddSeconds(rnd.Next(60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Comment: I suspect you want `date.Date.AddSeconds` so that the random time stays on the same date.

Comment: @Sean Thanks, that is correct. I updated the answer.

Comment: Just a tip, do NOT instantiate a new random every time you call this method. If you call it twice in quick succession, you may get identical results.